# Token errors, syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I am writing a function in Java, but I can't compile the code. I don't see the syntax error; can you help me?

```
public String getUserInput(String prompt){
    String inputLine = null;
    System.out.print(prompt + " ");
    try(
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        if (inputLine.length() == 0 ) 
            return null;
        ) 
    catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
    return inputLine.toLowerCase();
}
```

It doesn't compile.

Comment: if there is an error with your code it is useful if you post the error you get

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to go for checking your syntax errors.

Comment: For future reference, you can't execute a "statement list" within the confines of parenthesis, it must be within a block {}.

Comment: Especially when beginning Java programming, I _heavily_ recommend using an IDE ([NetBeans][http://netbeans.org] for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `(` and `)` enclosing your `try`-Block with `{` and `}`

Answer (score 2):

check the try block brackets,its `()` which is not allowed in java and reserved for methods.For block use `{}`

Correct answer

```
public String getUserInput(String prompt){
    String inputLine = null;
    System.out.print(prompt + " ");
    try
    //( this is wrong
    {
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        if (inputLine.length() == 0 ) 
            return null;
        //)
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
return inputLine.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps want [`try`-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (Java 7+)?

```
try (BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

    inputLine = is.readLine();

    if (inputLine.length() == 0)
        return null;

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
}
```

If not, then recall that standard [`try`-`catch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) blocks take the form:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (...) {

}
```

Notice the `{}` brackets.

Comment: As a note (and something you might want to add to your answer), try-with-resource is only available in Java 7 onward.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Indeed, I added it.

Comment: @arshajii +1 for try with resource.Well just wanted to know are there any advantage of using try with resource compared to old try-catch fashion?

Comment: @rocking try-with-resources is just easier. It explains this somewhat in my first link.

Comment: @rocking There is no performance difference. It's just for the programmer's convenience.